# What follows from Incompleteness about provability of partial correctness?

Tags: logic, incompleteness

A colleague and I can't figure out what our professor is getting at with this question:

> What follows from the incompleteness theorems about the provability of partial correctness assertions? What follows from the undecidability of the halting problem? Describe concrete instances for (families of) $A$, $B$, $\pi$ that show the difference!

Where $A$ is a precondition and $B$ a postcondition, and $\pi$ is the program. I think he might want to hear that incompleteness follows from undecidability, but I'm pretty much at a loss otherwise. Thanks!

Comment: You can see *Relationship with Gödel's incompleteness theorem* in [Undecidable problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem)

Comment: Yes I'm aware of the relationship in principle. I'd tentatively say that incompleteness leaves us with an inability to *prove* partial correctness. Further, I can say that undecidability leaves us with an inability to prove total correctness.